# STM SPI receive syntax

Tags: c++, c, stm32

I have done some searching and found many questions, but am not coming to a correct conclusion.  To start with the hardware design:
the STM32 is a host MCU for a SI4362 RX only radio that uses spi for communication. i have hard coded all the radio power up commands, and as written in the API for the SI4362:

> To apply a patch, the patch content has to be sent to the radio chip
> after POR but before issuing the POWER_UP command.
> ...The GPIO1 pin goes high when the radio is ready for receiving SPI
> commands. During the reset period, the radio cannot accept any SPI
> commands.
> ...Each line has to be sent to the chip as an eight byte long command.
> A CTS reply has to be read from the chip after each line.

i have created the patch into an array to be written through a for loop.  in my example code i am using an LED flashing at different rates to determine my location where i am stuck.

> Once the CTS value reads FFh then the read data is ready to be clocked
> out to the host MCU. The typical time for a valid FFh CTS reading is
> 20 μs.

So my code is getting stuck at the second for loop meaning my POR is working by sending the SDN pin low.  This powers up the SI4362 and draws the GPIO1 high as the first CTS.  then I go into the patch initialization that is 265 address array of 8 bytes per address. this is what it looks like higher up in declaration

```
...
uint8_t array_263[8] ={ 0xEF,0x7D,0x0D,0xB5,0xCF,0x00,0xC5,0x75 };
uint8_t array_264[8] ={ 0xE3,0xC6,0x0E,0x0B,0x10,0x44,0x10,0xEE };
uint8_t array_265[8] ={ 0x05,0x12,0x86,0x0D,0xC0,0xA5,0xF6,0x92 };

uint8_t *theArrays[] = {array_1,array_2,array_3,array_4,\
        array_5,array_6,array_7,array_8,array_9,\
        array_10,array_11,array_12,array_13,array_14,\
        array_15,array_16,array_17,array_18,array_19,\
...
```

I then transmit the first line of 8 bytes followed by the loop that is stuck waiting on the CTS from the SPI that should return a 0xFF.  i apoloogize if im not describing it well. i am just working on the prototype proof of concept and have not had good luck outsourcing on sites so far.

```
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDN_GPIO_Port, SDN_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);


while (!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, RX_DATA_Pin)) {
    HAL_Delay(500);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            HAL_Delay(30);
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            HAL_Delay(30);
        }
}

  for (int i = 0; i < 265; i ++)
    {

      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, theArrays[i],8, 50);

      do {
          HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,reg_data,1,50);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          HAL_Delay(100);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
          HAL_Delay(100);
      }while(*reg_data != 0xff);

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_Delay(30);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_Delay(30);
    }
```

Comment: Are you really sure HAL_SPI_Transmit()is working? In my experience, SPI-transmitt are often asynchronous implementations, meaning that a return from HAL_SPI_Transmit() is not the same as a working transmission.

Comment: I can't see that you are handling the slave select in your code (the NSEL-pin). See chapter 7.2.1 in [link](http://silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN633.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double checking a few datasheets it would seem that i wasnt getting the first SPI command input within the time recommended. here is updated code.  now i need to verify what im sending and receiving, so i will have to figure out the USART now to make that work.  i feel that it will require a different question altogether if i have one.  thank you @nilsie for looking at the code and mentioning the CS pin (i assumed that because i included it in MX it would work automatically within the HAL_transmit call)

```
/* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  // CS pin should default high
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SS_GPIO_Port, SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  uart_buf_len = sprintf(uart_buf, "SPI Test\r\n");

  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)uart_buf, uart_buf_len, 100);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDN_GPIO_Port, SDN_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_Delay(100);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_Delay(100);
    }

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDN_GPIO_Port, SDN_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SS_GPIO_Port, SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  int count = 0;

while (!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, RX_DATA_Pin) && count != 13) {
 HAL_Delay(1);
 count++;
}

count = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 265; i ++)
    {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SS_GPIO_Port, SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, theArrays[i],8, 50);
      do {
          HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)spi_buf, 1, 100);
      }while(*spi_buf != 0xFF);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SS_GPIO_Port, SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_Delay(20);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_Delay(20);
    }
```